# Remixd Error when Hooking up shared folder to Remix

Tags: remix

The first type of error occurs when I run the listener on my Windows 10 using a terminal (powershell).  The listener (remixd) starts OK then when I go to connect to the browser session I get the following:

```
PS C:\Windows\System32>  remixd -s D:\zz210201_shared_folder --remix-ide https://remix.ethereum.org
[WARN] You may now only use IDE at https://remix.ethereum.org to connect to that instance
[WARN] Any application that runs on your computer can potentially read from and write to all files in the directory.
[WARN] Symbolic links are not forwarded to Remix IDE

Wed Feb 03 2021 18:29:11 GMT+0700 (Indochina Time) Remixd is listening on 127.0.0.1:65520
setup notifications for D:\zz210201_shared_folder
Error: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'D:\System Volume Information'
```

When I use the desktop version I get the following errors when trying to make the connection.

```
Wed Feb 03 2021 18:13:57 GMT+0700 (Indochina Time) Remixd is listening on 127.0.0.1:65520
Wed Feb 03 2021 18:14:14 GMT+0700 (Indochina Time) Connection from origin package://6fd22d6fe5549ad4c4d8fd3ca0b7816b.mod rejected.
Wed Feb 03 2021 18:14:15 GMT+0700 (Indochina Time) Connection from origin package://6fd22d6fe5549ad4c4d8fd3ca0b7816b.mod rejected.
Wed Feb 03 2021 18:14:29 GMT+0700 (Indochina Time) Connection from origin package://6fd22d6fe5549ad4c4d8fd3ca0b7816b.mod rejected.
Wed Feb 03 2021 18:14:30 GMT+0700 (Indochina Time) Connection from origin package://6fd22d6fe5549ad4c4d8fd3ca0b7816b.mod rejected.
Wed Feb 03 2021 18:18:31 GMT+0700 (Indochina Time) Connection from origin https://remix.ethereum.org rejected.
Wed Feb 03 2021 18:18:32 GMT+0700 (Indochina Time) Connection from origin https://remix.ethereum.org rejected.
```

Not sure how to proceed to get it working.  Any clues appreciated.

Comment: stopped using any proxy and the behavior did change a bit.  Still get the EPERM error and can't read the directory from the remix browser page, but I can create and write files to localhost.  Just can't display what is in localhost.

Comment: sudo npm install -g @remix-project/remixd --force

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fix Remixd EPERM error](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/93085/remixd-error-when-hooking-up-shared-folder-to-remix)

```
npm uninstall -g remixd
npm install -g @remix-project/remixd --force
```